# How to fix tasks loop from looping only once?

Tags: python, loops, discord, discord.py

I have a loop on my Discord bot that should make a role switch color every half second. It was working before, but now it only loops once. The bot is in 12 servers, so not really an overload, and again, it was working fine before. There are no errors, it just runs once then stops. How do I fix this?
The code I'm using:

```
i = 0

@tasks.loop(seconds=0.5)
async def colors(bot):
    global i
    print('Switching Color')
    colorS = [0xff0000,0xff8000,0xffff00,0x00ff00,0x00ffff,0x0000ff,0xb600ff]
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="#rainbow")
        if(role == None):
            continue
        await role.edit(color=discord.Color(colorS[i]))
    i += 1
    if(i > 6):
        i = 0
```

I run it in my `on_ready` function with `colors.start(bot)`. Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Code works as desired for me.

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting rate limited. Changing colour every half second is quite fast.